# MIPS Encoding of blez/bgtz vs bltz/bgez

Tags: cpu, mips

In the MIPS architecture, `blez/bgtz` and `bltz/bgez` are encoded differently:

`blez/bgtz` are encoded as: [BLEZ/BGTZ: 6 bits] [RS: 5 bits] [0: 5 bits] [OFFSET: 16 bits]

`bltz/bgez` are encoded as: [REGIMM: 6 bits] [RS: 5 bits] [BLTZ/BGEZ: 5 bits] [OFFSET: 16 bits]

My question is:
Why didn't they encode all 4 branches into the `REGIMM` space which is more than large enough to accommodate them and many more?
Why waste 2 out of 64 instruction slots on `blez/bgtz` instead?

Comment: There aren't that many bits in REGIMM. Shared with conditional trap instructions, so one bit to distinguish B from T. Two more bits for And Link and Likely variants of branch. Just enough left over for BLEZ/BGTZ, but I would guess that because those two don't have the full variants that BLTZ and BGEZ do, they were added later. The MIPS designers didn't care too much about a regular instruction set if it would simplify the hardware.

Comment: @HughFisher Would you mind to turn this into an answer instead of a comment? It already contains all relevant points.

Comment: Since I wasn't involved in the MIPS design, and for that matter have never designed a CPU instruction set, I think this is a likely guess rather than an answer. There are (I think) just enough bits that the designers could have included the two additional branches if they'd wanted to.

Comment: @HughFisher - but conditional traps weren't there in the first version of MIPS - it was just bltz, bgez, bltzal, bgezal (source: mips IV pdf which shows encodings per vesion) - 3 bits were perfectly free for the taking back then.

Comment: @HughFisher If we would only allow answers from the genuine designers of some device/machine, RC.SE would be some dead end. But it isn't, it's a 'market' of solution offerings. So add yours.